# Rsync doesn't allow me copy files into mounted filesystems

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, rsync, raspberry-pi

I configured rsyncd.conf for public access in my rpi:

```
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
timeout = 600
max connections = 20
uid = nobody
gid = nogroup
read only = yes
list = yes

[public]
path = /home/pi/MISCELAN
comment = directorio misc
hosts allow = *
```

/home/pi/MISCELAN is a mounted filesystem in a USB device with this options in fstab:
/dev/sda1 /home/pi/MISCELAN ext4 rw,users,user,owner 0 0

In the client size I do:
rsync -vaz rsync://192.168.0.201/public .

But I get this permissions errors:
rsync: change_dir "/" (in public) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1536) [Receiver=3.0.9]

Rsync daemon works ok, if I change in rsyncd.conf the shared folder to, for example, /home/pi, I can get a copy of all files but not files into MISCELAN. Appears rsync cannot access to mounted filesystem MISCELAN ¿?

Any ideas?

EDIT: sorry, MISCELAN folder had restricted permissions, I'm stupid :-P

Comment: If you've found the solution you should post it as an answer, instead of editing your question.

Comment: Why are you configuring the rsync deamon and not just using SSH?